# inserted li disappears after to calling addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code:

```
<div id="tabItem">
  <ul id="lstOrdenes" class="nav">
    <li class="list-group col-md-4" id="1">
      <--CODE HERE-->                            
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my javascript code es:

```
function insert(id)
{
  var rowTemplate = '<li id="'+id+'" class="col-md-4" >[CODE HTML]</li>';

  $(rowTemplate).appendTo($("#tabItem ul#lstOrdenes"));
  alert("insert");
  $("#tabItem ul#lstOrdenes li#"+id).addClass("list-group");
}
```

When I called the javascript function to insert li and then display the alert message it is working correctly, but after executing `addClass("list-group")` the new li item added disappears.

But when I change `addClass("list-group")` by `addClass("another")` works right.

if class name of javascript `("another")` is different to the class name of HTML `("list-group")` works, but if the same the new li tab disappears.

Do anyone have any suggestions about this?

Comment: I can't reproduce problem.What disappears?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it disappears? Is the element gone from the DOM, or is it not just shown in the page?

Comment: You should provide your CSS as .list-group might have a display:none or something similar

Comment: class is probably attaching to wrong selector or in wrong order.

Comment: before to alert message view by firefox debbuger i can see de code but after the message this code disappears
 css list-group is:
li.list-group {
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 1px !important;
        width: 33% !important;
        float: left;
    }

Comment: What library has `list-group`? What triggers the `insert` method? We need the details to answer the question.